# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime [SQL SERVER 2008 R2]

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, reporting-services

I have this query below and I keep getting an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime error

when executing. I am pretty sure it has to do with `DATE_ID =` etc etc, because every time I put in a timestamp in their it works. Can anyone help me ?

```
SELECT 
    Dimension.[Every 10 minutes], 
    COUNT(*) as [Number of Transactions], 
    df.[Function Name]
FROM 
    dbo.table, Dimension, DimensionFunction df
WHERE 
    DATE_ID = DATEADD(day, -1, convert(varchar(50), GETDATE(),20))
    AND dbo.table.TIME = Dimension.Time
    AND df.FUNCTION_CODE = dbo.table.FUNCTION_CODE
    AND INTERFACE_ID = 2
    AND dbo.table.FUNCTION_CODE in ('ABX', 'BBB','DDD','EEE')
    AND TABLE.TIME BETWEEN '07:00' and '17:59'
GROUP BY
    Dimension.[Every 10 minutes], df.[Function Name]
ORDER BY
    Dimension.[Every 130 minutes], df.[Function Name]
```

Comment: Please stop using Old-style-joins, read here why: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Why you convert the `GETDATE` to varchar when the `DATEADD` will convert it again to datetime?

Comment: what is the data type of date_id field?

Comment: DATE_ID is int and I didn't know about GETDATE re-converting it. can you help me with an easier solution? or guide me to a better way?

Comment: the query ran when I changed it into :

 where DATE_ID = convert(varchar(50), GETDATE() -1 ,112)

thank you for helping me realize I didn't need to use DATEADD